# R data.table simple replacing of a whole row

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

So I'm trying to do something so simple that it amazes me how complicated it turns out to be.

Given a simple data.table, I just want to replace its first row by a vector of length equal to the number of columns in the data.table.

Simple enough, right ? Not quite. Enter the ridiculously convoluted world of data.table indexing.

```
x = data.table(stupidColumnA=22, stupidColumnB=33)
x[1, ] = c(100, 200)
```

Why in the world would this intuitive syntax that works in every programming language spit this out:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 1, , value = c(100, 200)) :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'stupidColumnA' (1 unused)
2: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 1, , value = c(100, 200)) :
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'stupidColumnB' (1 unused)
```

is beyond me. What's even more mind bending is that searching online for like 15 minutes was totally and utterly fruitless.

Needless to say, anything more complicated than a one-liner to accomplish this basic task is just bad design in my opinion, so I've given up on data.table for this. Doing it with an ugly cast to data.frame works as expected, just because.

```
> xx = as.data.frame(x)
> xx[1, ] = c(100, 200)
> xx
  stupidColumnA stupidColumnB
1  100  200
```

But I am just curious. What would a data.table-only solution look like ?

**Edit (Solution):**

For some reason this question is deemed unworthy, unrealistic (i.e. will never occur in practice) and hence is down-voted. Anyway the solution is:

`xx[1, (colnames(xx)):= list(1,2)]`

in case anyone stumbles across this highly theoretical problem

Comment: I suggest you read the data.table vignettes.

Comment: No answer there

Comment: Please also see first example in **Usage** in `?:=`: `DT[i, c("LHS1", "LHS2") := list(RHS1, RHS2), by = ...]`, or the [vignette on reference semantics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html), e.g. "LHS takes a character vector of column names and RHS a list of values. RHS just needs to be a list, irrespective of how its generated". Of course I can't speak for the downvoters, but my guess is that all the rant in your question may have contributed to the negative receptions. You may consider an edit. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xx[1, (colnames(xx)):= list(1,2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question reads like somebody complaining that it's difficult to hook a trailer to a Lamborghini. Your car dealer will tell you to buy a truck instead of a race car.

If replacing a row by an atomic vector seems like a regular task to you a matrix would appear to be the appropriate data structure for you.

If you want to use data.table you should just reshape your data to long format and then use the reference semantics together with subsetting:

```
longDT[observationNo == 1, values := replacementVector]
```

Comment: A more appropriate car analogy imho would be to say that I'm complaining that my super fancy futuristic 25th-century car doesn't have a gas pedal. 

Me: "This car doesn't have a gas pedal. Ridiculous"
Dealer: "But it can fly and travel across time and universes."
Me: "Yeah...gas pedal"

Comment: I'm a heavy user of data.table. I've never needed to replace a row with an atomic vector. To me this screams that you either shouldn't use a data.table or a data.frame but a matrix or your data is not tidy (see the definition in Hadley Wickham's [publication](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf)) and you should reshape your data.

Comment: Note that columns of a data.table can contain different data types which you can't combine in a vector. Try your approach with a replacement list. It should work but you should still use assignment by reference as my answer shows.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to fly, why even use data.table? The analogy could be asking for the gas pedal in a plane.

Comment: I'm a heavy user of data.table as well and even with solid computer science background the world of data.table indexing always seems infinite to me. 

This use case is a basic and frequent update operation that actually works if you use conditional indexing on the rows. And the fact that it works seemlessly with data.frame speaks for itself.

Anyway I was hoping for a one-liner (in addition to the standard "change you approach" responses, Managed to luck out on it:

`xx[1, (colnames(xx)):= list(1,2)]`

Comment: Obviously I wouldn't reject a time-travelling, universe-crossing car for lack of a gas pedal. This was an analogy, and as any analogy it breaks when taken literally. The idea is that sophisticated functionality often comes at the expense of basic, intuitive needs that just get sacked. The choice then is either to produce a convoluted solution or "change your approach". Fortunatelly in this case it is neither